# Connection refused using Node.js, caused by an "index.js" file I didn't even know existed

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client

I want to make a very simple client-server web application. I followed a tutorial step by step to make this "Hello World" program:

Server (server.js):

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', client => {
    client.emit('init', { data: 'hello world' });
});

io.listen(3000);
```

Client (client.js):

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('init', handleInit);

function handleInit(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

And I linked socket.io to my HTML (index.html) so I could use the global io object:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
```

However, instead of printing out "{data: hello world}" on the console, I get these error messages:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
        
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OQ8ARql net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED index.js:83
```

The latter message shows up again every few seconds. It refers to an ominous "index.js" at line 83. I have no idea what this is. Following the link, I noticed that it seems to be part of my IP address (http://127.0.0.1:56966). Line 83 looks like this:

```
Backoff.prototype.setJitter = function(jitter){
  this.jitter = jitter;
};
```

I have no idea what causes this or how to fix it. It happens no matter which port I select.

Comment: *"I also get an error message because of some "missing favicon" even though I never stated that there should be a favicon."* You can ignore that. Browsers (or at least Chromium browsers) always ask for a favicon, even if the page doesn't say it has one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay that's a relief, thank you. How about the refused connection? Why might that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

> It refers to an ominous "index.js" at line 83. I have no idea what this is

Click on it. It will take you to a debugging screen.

I think its part of the code generated by *socket.io.js*.

---

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OQ8ARql net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED index.js:83

Connection Refused just means that the browser trying to connect to port 3000 to make its HTTP request and the computer responded with "No" which means that either:

- Nothing is listening on that port of that network interface
- It is firewalled

Since it is localhost, it is *really* unlikely to be firewalled.

Your code says:

> ```
> io.listen(3000);
> ```

So you're written a server that listens on that port, but the connection to it can't be made.

The most likely explanation is that you **haven't run the program**:

```
node server.js
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried running "node server.js" in the terminal, but now I get the following errors: 

1. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OQ8YxMJ' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:60225' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OQ8YxMJ:1          
2. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
:60225/favicon.ico:1          
3. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)